# Hosting Spring-cloud-config server as a micro service in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

How to host a Spring cloud config server registered as Eureka Client in Docker containers ?

My Spring Boot micro services architecture includes the below components:

1. eureka-server (Eureka as Service Registry)
2. config-server (registered as Eureka client)
3. Business Logic App (registered as Eureka client)

These Spring Boot applications are working fine in my Windows local machine.  The same needs to be hosted in Docker containers.

**Step 1:**
I have created an image of Eureka server in Docker and executed as a container.  I'm able to access the eureka server with the url - http://localhost:8761

**Step 2:**
I have created an image of config server which acts as a Eureka client and executed as a container.  On start up of this service, I'm facing errors.

Below are the error,

```
 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.12.jar!/:1.9.12]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
```

Config server is not getting registered with Eureka server while running in Docker container.

I have tried including the below key-value in my config-server properties as suggested in many blogs:

- trail 1: eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
- trail 2: eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/

Both these suggestions don't work.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Would you amend this question to show the config files that a reader would need in order to replicate the problem? If you can expand on what "doesn't work" means, that would be good too - errors? unexpected outputs? unusual logs? etc.

Comment: Hi @halfer, I have updated the description with the error logs.  Could you please suggest any solution to resolve this.

Comment: That is much better. I have removed the request for a "working example" as that probably falls foul of "request for external resources" (from the official hold reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_). Readers may also read that as a "fix it for me", which is generally not well received.

Comment: When you say _"I'm able to access the eureka server with the url - http://localhost:8761"_, have you tried this from inside the container itself?

Comment: Thank you !!

I'm able to see that the Eureka server is up and running when i hit the URL in my browser.

Comment: OK. That's not your container though - I assume it exists in one container and you want to fetch from it in another container. So, `localhost` is not going to work, since it is not hosted in that localhost. You need to work out what DNS name or IP to use.

Comment: Your Eureka container is probably using a host-exposed port (8761) which connects is to the localhost of the host machine, which is why your browser can see it.

Comment: Hi @halfer,

Thanks much for your help.  I have resolved the reported problem.

I had connectivity problem between the containers.  

I resolved by creating a custom network and run my containers in that network.  Then I was able to establish connection between containers using the container name.

For Example,  My config server is now able to connect to Eureka using the URL - http://eureka-server:8761

Comment: That sounds about right, good stuff. I have moved it to an answer for you. If you would like to repost it under your own account, please do so; let me know and I will delete my copy.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author, in order to move it to an answer)*.

I have resolved the reported problem. I had connectivity problem between the containers.

**I resolved by creating a custom network and run my containers in that network.  Then I was able to establish connection between containers using the container name.**

For example, my config server is now able to connect to Eureka using the URL - http://eureka-server:8761.